# I need to drive a 7/16" nut but am unsure how to use the socket I bought for my screwdriver

Tags: tools, socket

[image]

I have this 7/16" hex nut (in front) and I tried to order in amazon an adapter that can make my 1/4 hex bit torque screwdriver drive it. When I received the package. It was all wrong. The 7/16" was the size of the hex bit and the 1/2 is the size of the square wrench (I need all to be hexagon or 6 sides, not 4 sided).

What is the proper way to do this?

I also bought adapter for 1/4 hex to 1/2 hex thinking the male size was 1/2 size (when it fact it was 7/16" size)

[image]

Comment: Can you take a picture of the other side of the socket? The package says 1/2" drive and that seems to be the end we're looking at

Comment: I thought the 1/2 was the male end.. but how does one differentiate between 4 sided or 6 sided drive.. was it the SAE? see added pic above..

Comment: "Socket, 1/2-Inch Drive" is the standard 1/2-inch square "hole" on the one end of your adapter. You did get exactly what you ordered... even it it's not what you intended. "SAE" means that things are measured in inches (7/16") - the alternative would have been "Metric" (11mm).

Comment: SAE stands for “Society of Automotive Engineering” and a 4 sided socket is called a square or 4 point socket. A six sided socket is called a six point socket. In terms of socket usage, the fewer points you have increases the amount of torque that can be applied without the socket slipping on the bolt or nut. "Drive" refers to the shank that is either attached to or can be attached to the socket in question.

Comment: The green package is, as it says an "adapter and reducer set". This allows you to use a 1/2" drive socket on a 3/8" drive ratchet or any of the other combinations that are available in that package. I would suggest returning that set - you probably won't need them, and they certainly won't help you with this particular project.

Comment: [Klein Tools 7/16 in. Nut Driver](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Klein-Tools-7-16-in-Nut-Driver-with-3-in-Hollow-Shaft-Cushion-Grip-Handle-630-7-16/202282839), or just buy a socket set that also comes with a screw driver, otherwise you'll be asking this question again when you need other sizes. And to tighten a bolt well, you'll need that huge grip from e.g., Klein, or the leverage of a wrench.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this type of nut driver - 1/4” hex drive and various sizes in A/F and metric :

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B01J3O4RYS/ref=sspa_mb_hqp_detail_mobile_aax_0?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01J3O4RYS)

But there are probably other suppliers with differing quality...

Comment: I ordered this already. The various sizes will help. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

You need two things.... [**1/4" drive 7/16" socket**](https://www.grainger.com/product/53YR05?gclid=CjwKCAjw96fkBRA2EiwAKZjFTe0z2hNf5ANh7cWOgrwsepZKxyn_yT0WI7xP41FZLVclmMCUC5fHMhoCZ0wQAvD_BwE&cm_mmc=PPC:%20Google%20PLA&ef_id=CjwKCAjw96fkBRA2EiwAKZjFTe0z2hNf5ANh7cWOgrwsepZKxyn_yT0WI7xP41FZLVclmMCUC5fHMhoCZ0wQAvD_BwE:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!50916805797!!!g!82128473037!)

[image]

...and a [**1/4" hex shank socket adapter**](https://www.globalindustrial.com/p/tools/Drills-Drivers-Bits/drill-bits/48-32-5033-1-4-hex-shank-socket-adapter-set-3pc?unbxdSuggestion=SUGGESTION%20-%20Milwaukee%2048-32-5033%20SHOCKWAVE%201/4%22%20Hex%20Shank%20Socket%20Adapter%20Set%203PC.&q=1/4%20hex%20drive%20socket%20set)...

[image]

That adapter kit will allow you to use multiple drives of sockets for hundreds of future uses. You probably already have some sockets. There are some one piece cheapos on the market that do work, but you have to buy all new kits when either the shank or socket portion wears down or breaks.

Comment: In the wrongly sent package. It was written "Capri Tools 7/16-Inch Hex Bit Socket, 1/2-Inch Drive, SAE"  There was no 4 side written. Does SAE mean 4 sided? When I order, what's the name for 6 sided?

Comment: @Jtl "7/16" refers to the 6- or 12-point opening designed to attach to the fastener. "1/2-drive" refers to the square opening that is designed to attach to the socket wrench (or socket adapter as shown in this answer). As described in other answers, you simply need a `7/16" socket`. For something that small, a 3/8" drive is all that's needed - a 1/2" drive will allow you to apply significantly more torque and you could end up over tightening your nut (depending on usage).

Answer (score 12):

What you bought was a **hex bit socket**, not a simple hex socket.

[image: hex bit socket set]

What's confusing you here is the bit coming out of the **top** of the socket. You've confused that for a drill shank. The square portion is where you would attach a 1/2" ratchet (or drill socket adapter, like Jerry described in his answer). Harbor Freight [describes their hex bit set like this](https://www.harborfreight.com/6-pc-38-in-drive-metric-hex-socket-set-69546.html)

> Ideal for removing and replacing hex fasteners in automotive and machinery applications, such as hex cap bolts and screws, this hex bit socket set is perfect for any shop or garage.

What you need to buy is a regular 7/16" socket (these are common) and a drill socket adapter (Jerry covered that in his answer)

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is 1/4 X1/4 Hex driver. Go to Home Depot, Lowes, Ace Hardware or any large hardware or tool type store. Tell them what you want and they can sell you what you need  I have all sizes and if you were my neighbor you could have 1 of mine.